# Create table as ( using a column and table name)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to build a table from several tables in MySql and I want it has two columns like:

```
-------------------
name | table_name |
-------------------
```

I'm doing this:

```
Create table teams as 
(
Select name from table1
union
Select name from table2
union
Select name from table3);
```

How could I include each table name as a second column??

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I'm new here! thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow then! We hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Sorry again, I'm getting this:

MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table from england union Select name,'primera' AS table from primera u' at line 3

any idea?

Comment: Do you have a table or column actually named `table`? If so, you need to quote it in backticks, since `table` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Oh I see, you're probably using `table` as the alias.  Yes, quote it in backticks. I'll update my answer too...  I believe it is also valid to quote aliases with single quotes in MySQL.

Comment: You were right, I changed 'table' for 'tableName' but I got the same:

MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union Select name, `primera` AS tableName from primera union Select na' at line 4

for this code:

Create table equipos as 
(
  Select name, `england` AS tableName from england
  union 
  Select name, `primera` AS tableName from primera
  union
  Select name, `segunda` AS tableName from segunda
);

:S

Comment: Due to parentheses.  Enclose each select query in a `()` group, or enclose none of them.  Don't enclose the whole outer structure in `()` following the `CREATE TABLE AS`. Updated below.

Comment: Now it works perfectly!!! Thank you very much! Can I give you any badge as a reward?

Comment: Accepted answer and satisfaction are the reward. Happy to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include a quoted string literal. Be sure to also give it a column alias, which will be used as the column name in the resultant table.

```
CREATE TABLE teams AS 
  /* Quoted string literal with column alias */
  (SELECT name, 'table1' AS `tablename` FROM table1)
  UNION 
  (SELECT name, 'table2' AS `tablename` FROM table2)
  UNION
  (SELECT name, 'table3' AS `tablename` FROM table3);
```

Note that since you are in effect adding a second value to each row which differentiates it from potentially similar rows in the other tables, the `UNION` is now the eqivalent of a `UNION ALL`, and duplicate rows won't be de-duped as the plan `UNION` would have. Just beware, that the results may differ from what your original `UNION` produced.